# How to take a screenshot of a web-page with embed flash using JavaScript or some flash plugin

Tags: javascript, flash, screenshot, html

I know the html2canvas library, but it doesn't work with flash and iframes elements. But my be  a flash library can avoid these restrictions.

Or a flash player that can take screenshots of current playing video.

Comment: taking screenshot means, do you need to save the captured image in server?

Comment: yes, i could use html2canvas and send to the server in base64 format, but there is a flash video player on the page  which must be captured too. The another idea is to capture  the video in the flash player if it would have API to do it and then merge on the server the result of html2canvas and screenshot of the video in the player, but i don't know such players.

Comment: you can create an application which loads swf and captures the stage as bitmap data and sends it to server. Create a javascript call back function in it so that you can trigger the save method from javascript. Then you can save the captured image into server as you need and merge it and use it for your purpose. Check this [link](http://subashflash.blogspot.in/2013/10/save-image-from-as2-project-using-as3.html). This demonstrates how to save image into server by loading a swf into an application. Hope it helps.